# How does an android test project have visibility on classes from the main project?

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair

I'm trying to understand how testing can be applied in android and have followed this walkthrough on the Google site.

I've created a project for the application itself via the wizard in IntelliJ. Then I've created a test project using the following :

```
android create test-project -m ../TestableProject -n TestableProjectTests -p TestableProjectTests
```

I've opened up the test project, and had a look at the `MyActivityTest` class it auto generated, however it seems unable to resolve the location of `MyActivity` in the main project, for example this doesn't work :

```
import com.example.MyActivity;
```

My question is, how can the test project have visibility on classes from the main application project its trying to test? I can see the following in the manifest of the test project but that doesn't seem to help a great deal :

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
                     android:targetPackage="com.example"
                     android:label="Tests for com.example"/>
```

How can I enable my test project to see my application project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer that worked for me.

Since I'm using intelliJ, I needed to import the test project into the main project as a module. It uses the same project files, just makes it visible as a module so the projects can see each other

Documented here : http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/09/android-unit-testing-support/